# Finding the determinant of a matrix generated by an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have an equation that gives each entry of a square matrix of size $d+1 \times d+1$ with row $i$ and column $s$.

$$(-1)^{i+1}\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}\sum_{\ell=0}^{3(d-j)}{s-1\choose j} {3(d-j)\choose \ell } {3j\choose 3i-3-\ell}(-2)^\ell (-1)^{j}$$

So given $d=2$ we can get a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
160 & 171 & 162\\
64 & 72 & 81\end{pmatrix}$$

My goal is to find the formula for the determinant of the matrix for any given $d$.

I was able to get the invariant factors by looking at the matrix's Smith normal form and create a sequence log 3 from it.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 9 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 243\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}3^0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3^2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3^5\end{pmatrix}
\text{which gives the sequence } \{0,2,5 \} \text{ log 3}.$$

If I stack the sequence of numbers as $d$ increases I can get this triangle,

[image: not quite a triangle]

and removing the zeroes...

[image: triangle]

My thought process is that if I can find a formula that will give the sum of each line then I'll have the determinant log 3. Looking through the online integer sequence database returned nothing.

I did find regular patterns when taking the difference of each element in the sequence. Of note is that the sum of each row in this subsequence is $3d-1$.

[image: My computer took 30 minutes to get this triangle]

Can someone let me know if I'm going about this the wrong way? I've been staring at triangles all week and am going crazy.